# Console Application in WF4 not moving to next activity- Shopping Cart

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I am developing a shopping cart console WF application modelling Online Shopping Cart like this: https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/15e24iO-OCcQuO7PwqQVJpTOd1RHs4e042S-zyjL1iu0/pub?w=1001&h=728

I am using a bookmark activity which read input from Console. So 3 bookmark activities r used to read `ItemID`, `Qty`, `ContinueShopping`

Inside while activity. At Continue Shopping activity if I enter Yes, after entering ItemID. nothing is happening at the console.

It should ask the next activity "Enter Qty"? rt? What is the issue. Plz guide me.

Xaml:

```
 <Activity mc:Ignorable="sads sap" x:Class="OnlineShoppingCartWorkFlow.ShoppingCartWorkflow" local:ShoppingCartWorkflow.IsContinueArg="Y" local:ShoppingCartWorkflow.OrderIDArg="0"
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:OnlineShoppingCartWorkFlow"
 xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
 xmlns:mv="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic;assembly=System"
 xmlns:mva="clr-namespace:Microsoft.VisualBasic.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:s1="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System"
 xmlns:s2="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Xml"
 xmlns:s3="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.Core"
 xmlns:s4="clr-namespace:System;assembly=System.ServiceModel"
 xmlns:sa="clr-namespace:System.Activities;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:sad="clr-namespace:System.Activities.Debugger;assembly=System.Activities"
 xmlns:sads="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2010/xaml/activities/debugger"
 xmlns:sap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2009/xaml/activities/presentation"
 xmlns:scg="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System"
 xmlns:scg1="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.ServiceModel"
 xmlns:scg2="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=System.Core"
 xmlns:scg3="clr-namespace:System.Collections.Generic;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:sd="clr-namespace:System.Data;assembly=System.Data"
 xmlns:sl="clr-namespace:System.Linq;assembly=System.Core"
 xmlns:st="clr-namespace:System.Text;assembly=mscorlib"
 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <x:Members>
    <x:Property Name="IsContinueArg" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="OrderIDArg" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
    <x:Property Name="QtyArg" Type="InArgument(x:String)" />
  </x:Members>
  <sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize>632,1674</sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize>
  <mva:VisualBasic.Settings>Assembly references and imported namespaces for internal implementation</mva:VisualBasic.Settings>
  <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
      <x:Boolean x:Key="ShouldCollapseAll">False</x:Boolean>
      <x:Boolean x:Key="ShouldExpandAll">True</x:Boolean>
    </scg3:Dictionary>
  </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
  <Sequence DisplayName="Sequence1" sad:XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="G:\Development\Shopping Cart\WFShoppingCart\WFShoppingCart\WFShopping.xaml" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="592,1634">
    <Sequence.Variables>
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg3:List(local:Product)" Default="[New List(Of Product)]" Name="varStockList" />
      <Variable x:TypeArguments="scg3:List(local:Product)" Default="[New List(Of Product)]" Name="varShoppingCart" />
    </Sequence.Variables>
    <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
        <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
      </scg3:Dictionary>
    </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
    <Assign DisplayName="Get Stock &amp; Assign" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="570,60">
      <Assign.To>
        <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="scg3:List(local:Product)">[varStockList]</OutArgument>
      </Assign.To>
      <Assign.Value>
        <InArgument x:TypeArguments="scg3:List(local:Product)">[New Product().GetStock()]</InArgument>
      </Assign.Value>
    </Assign>
    <Sequence DisplayName="SequenceWhile" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="570,1410">
      <Sequence.Variables>
        <Variable x:TypeArguments="x:Int32" Default="0" Name="varBillAmount" />
      </Sequence.Variables>
      <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
          <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
        </scg3:Dictionary>
      </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
      <While DisplayName="While Continue Shopping" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="548,1185">
        <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">False</x:Boolean>
            <x:Boolean x:Key="IsPinned">False</x:Boolean>
          </scg3:Dictionary>
        </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
        <While.Condition>[IsContinueArg.ToUpper() = "Y"]</While.Condition>
        <Sequence DisplayName="SequenceWhileBody" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="522,1067">
          <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
            <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
              <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
            </scg3:Dictionary>
          </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
          <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="500,61" Text="Enter the ProductID:" />
          <local:MyReadLine BookmarkName="IDBookmark" DisplayName="Read OrderID" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="500,22" Result="[OrderIDArg]" />
          <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="500,61" Text="Enter the Qty:" />
          <local:MyReadLine BookmarkName="QtyBookmark" DisplayName="Read Qty" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="500,22" Result="[QtyArg]" />
          <If Condition="[varStockList.Exists(Function(x) x.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(OrderIDArg) And x.Quantity &gt;= Convert.ToInt32(QtyArg))]" DisplayName="Check Stock Availablity" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="500,454">
            <If.Then>
              <Sequence DisplayName="SequenceIfTrue" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="264,346">
                <Sequence.Variables>
                  <Variable x:TypeArguments="local:Product" Default="[New Product()]" Name="varAddProduct" />
                </Sequence.Variables>
                <sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                  <scg3:Dictionary x:TypeArguments="x:String, x:Object">
                    <x:Boolean x:Key="IsExpanded">True</x:Boolean>
                  </scg3:Dictionary>
                </sap:WorkflowViewStateService.ViewState>
                <Assign DisplayName="Assign Prodcut" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="242,60">
                  <Assign.To>
                    <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="local:Product">[varAddProduct]</OutArgument>
                  </Assign.To>
                  <Assign.Value>
                    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="local:Product">[varStockList.Find(Function(x) x.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(OrderIDArg))]</InArgument>
                  </Assign.Value>
                </Assign>
                <Assign DisplayName="Assign Qty Of Product" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="242,60">
                  <Assign.To>
                    <OutArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">[varAddProduct.Quantity]</OutArgument>
                  </Assign.To>
                  <Assign.Value>
                    <InArgument x:TypeArguments="x:Int32">[Convert.ToInt32(QtyArg)]</InArgument>
                  </Assign.Value>
                </Assign>
                <AddToCollection x:TypeArguments="local:Product" Collection="[varShoppingCart]" DisplayName="AddToCollectionShoppingCart&lt;Product&gt;" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="242,22" Item="[varAddProduct]" />
              </Sequence>
            </If.Then>
            <If.Else>
              <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="211,61" Text="Item is out of stock!" />
            </If.Else>
          </If>
          <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="500,61" Text="Shopping Continue Y/N?" />
          <local:MyReadLine BookmarkName="ContinueBookmark" DisplayName="Read Shopping Continue" sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="500,22" Result="[IsContinueArg]" />
        </Sequence>
      </While>
      <WriteLine sap:VirtualizedContainerService.HintSize="548,61" Text="[&quot;Thank you customer. Your bill amount is Rs:&quot; + varShoppingCart.Sum(Function(x) x.Price * x.Quantity).ToString() + &quot;/ only&quot;]" />
    </Sequence>
  </Sequence>
</Activity>
```

I am using custom activity called MyReadLine class which is derived from NativeActivity. This activity read input from

Console. And it's a bookmark activity.

Program.cs file:>

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Activities;
using System.Activities.Statements;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
namespace OnlineShoppingCartWorkFlow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            WorkflowApplication wfApp = new WorkflowApplication(new ShoppingCartWorkflow());
            AutoResetEvent idleEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            wfApp.Idle = delegate(WorkflowApplicationIdleEventArgs e)
            {
                idleEvent.Set();
            };
            wfApp.Run();

            idleEvent.WaitOne();
            string bookmarkName = "IDBookmark";
            BookmarkResumptionResult result = wfApp.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, Console.ReadLine());
            bookmarkName = "QtyBookmark";
            result = wfApp.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, Console.ReadLine());
            bookmarkName = "ContinueBookmark";
            result = wfApp.ResumeBookmark(bookmarkName, Console.ReadLine());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }   
}
```

My Custom Activity class:

```
using System.Activities;

namespace OnlineShoppingCartWorkFlow
{
    public class MyReadLine : NativeActivity<string>
    {
        [RequiredArgument]
        public InArgument<string> BookmarkName { get; set; }
        protected override void Execute(NativeActivityContext context)
        {
            context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkName.Get(context), new BookmarkCallback(OnResumeBookmark));
            //context.CreateBookmark(BookmarkName.Get(context), new BookmarkCallback(OnResumeBookmark),  BookmarkOptions.MultipleResume);
        }   
        protected override bool CanInduceIdle
        {
            get
            {
                { return true; }
            }
        }
        public void OnResumeBookmark(NativeActivityContext context, Bookmark bookmark, object obj)
        {
            Result.Set(context, (string)obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem on this is that usually created the `xaml` file in a path that you changed (i.e., when you change your project to another folder)
In your `codebehing` you have:

```
XamlDebuggerXmlReader.FileName="G:\Development\Shopping Cart\WFShoppingCart\WFShoppingCart\WFShopping.xaml"
```

Please, check if your `xaml` "Full Path" Property is the same than this.
Once both are equal, you can debug your activity.